# How do the icons in TinyMCE work?

Tags: tinymce-4

I can't seem to be able to find any information about this on the interwebs, but how do the icons in TinyMCE 4 work?

I know I can specify icons for buttons by name and specify custom icons for my custom buttons, but what if I wanted to take one of the standard icons, modify it in an image editing application and then save it as a custom icon. Where do I get the source image for that icon? Where can I see the full list of available icons and their names?

Comment: Did you check here http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_skin?

Comment: Thank you, useful link a good starting point to get me going. Although I think it would be even better to have a comprehensive answer on this site that would explain how the icons work. The content of the linked page seems a bit terse.

Comment: Did you even bother read documentation? It clearly states "You can import the existing TinyMCE icons by uploading the "icomoon.dev.svg" file and then add more icons or change the ones we use. Adding more icons requires you to alter the Icons.less file and Icons.ie7.less file." If you really want to learn deeply how it works, visit their github page https://github.com/tinymce

Comment: Yes, I did bother reading the documentation. Stack overflow is a site to compile knowledge in a Q&A format as such it is encouraged to ask questions to get appropriate answers. Why don't you add an answer instead. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, here is, possible, a partial answer to my own question or at least what I have managed to understand based on the poor documentation that currently exists for this aspect of TinyMCE 4.

Icons in TinyMCE 4.x use a custom [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) font. The files for this font go in the skins//fonts directory.

If you [download the TinyMCE Dev Package](https://www.tinymce.com/download/), you can find in js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/Icons.less all the icons that are available for that particular skin and you will be able to use those icons for your custom buttons (if you are using that skin).

You need to use the word between "-i-" and ":before". e.g. if the definition in Icons.less is:

```
.@{prefix}-i-alignleft:before
```

You can use the keyword `alignleft` as an icon for your custom button.

I haven't gotten as far as adding more icons to the default set, but I guess it would involve creating a new theme, hopefully inheriting from a parent theme, and defining your own Icons.less file and then process that LESS file to generate the appropriate CSS for your theme.